# How to identify increasing and decreasing intervals when the derivative has a vertical asymptote but the original function doesn't?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How would I identify increasing and decreasing intervals when the derivative has a vertical asymptote but the original function doesn't?

For example: If I have $f(x)=x^{\frac{2}{3}}$, then that is defined for all $x$ in the real numbers.

However, $f^\prime(x)=\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{-1}{3}}$ is not defined at $x=0$.

So, would the interval at which $f$ is increasing be $x$ greater than or equal to $0$? Or, would it be $x>0$?

Comment: Is it true that if $a, b\in[0,\infty)$ and $a<b$ then $a^{2/3}<b^{2/3}$? If the answer is yes, then the function is increasing on $[0,\infty)$

Comment: Note that for the application of the derivative criterion for a real function $f$ on an interval $[a,b]$, it is
enough that $f$ is only differentiable on $(a,b)$ but continuous on $[a,b]$.